# Ruby compare non-latin characters

Tags: ruby, encoding

I have a program that need to compare strings with spanish characters (óáàñ).

Unfortunately this code doesn't even compile:

```
if str == "Caló"
    puts "OK!"
```

I've tried to place

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

in the top of the file, but the same 'invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)' appears.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try then

```
if str.encode('utf-8') == "Caló"
    puts "OK!"
end
```

or if not work then

```
if str.force_encoding('utf-8') == "Caló"
        puts "OK!"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your file is in UTF-8 format? It might be in Windows-1252 instead if that's what you're using.

Some editors allow you to pick the encoding format of the file it saves. If so, check that you're saving in UTF-8.

The `# encoding` header doesn't magically convert anything, it just sets how to interpret the file.